# Not able to locate text field in a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium

I have created code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")

inputElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "    (//input[@id='search_str'])[1]")))
inputElement.send_keys('IOC')
inputElement.submit()

assert driver.title == 'IOC Share Price, IOC Stock Price, Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. Stock Price, Share Price, Live BSE/NSE, Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. Bids Offers. Buy/Sell Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. news & tips, & F&O Quotes, NSE/BSE Forecast News and Live Quotes'

driver.quit()
```

Can anyone guide on how can we enter value and hit enter?

Comment: Are you waiting at all for the page to load?

Comment: Yes. Using driver.implicitly_wait(10)

Comment: @sam better using explicity wait for particular element

Comment: @same have you just forgotten to delete excess initializing driver and driver.get()?

Comment: @Vova : do you mean driver.delete()

Comment: @same i mean in your updated code snipped driver = chrome() 2 times

Comment: yes thanks updated now

Comment: You guys still having problems>

Comment: @sam Add what errors you see.

Comment: No error but it doesn't work after loading moneycontrol.com page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")
inputElement=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#form_topsearch>.txtsrchbox.FL'))) 
inputElement.send_keys('IOC',Keys.ENTER)
```

You can use page load strategy to stop the long page load to click on the input and then send Keys.ENTER to the input tag. Currently gets to the page with the

```
information you’re about to submit is not secure Because this form is being submitted using a connection that’s not secure, your information will be visible to others.
```

Then use

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#proceed-button'))).click()
```

Which should produce

[image]

Import

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: `page_load_strategy` is interesting idea

Comment: Finally, this strategy worked and it loaded perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's already workable solution, but for Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.moneycontrol.com")

inputElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//input[@id='search_str'])[1]")))
inputElement.send_keys('IOC')
inputElement.submit()

assert driver.title == 'IOC Share Price, IOC Stock Price, Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. Stock Price, Share Price, Live BSE/NSE, Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. Bids Offers. Buy/Sell Indian Oil Corporation Ltd. news & tips, & F&O Quotes, NSE/BSE Forecast News and Live Quotes'

driver.quit()
```

is Firefox required?

Comment: Not necessarily but tried on chrome, its not working in chrome too.

Comment: @sam works for me in chrome perfectly, update with assertion, passing well. btw, I left only .submit()

Comment: What look interesting is, its working on your chrome but not mine, let me test on safari

Comment: No error, nothing happen after opening moneycontrol.com. Let me post my updated code

Comment: @sam what selenium version do you use, webdriver one?

Comment: `//input[@id='search_str'])[1]` does not work for me

Comment: @vitaliis with open-closed () should works, but it can be skipped and just used with //input[@id='search_str'], coz searched one is the first

Comment: `options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')` - this is good idea. The site has security issues.

Comment: @vitaliis : I am using mac so probably the issue?

Comment: google-chrome version is 89.0.4389 and LATEST driver version for 89.0.4389

Comment: @sam might help re-using previously create browser profile

Comment: What I am not understanding is, is it mac specific issue for running the code?

Comment: @sam i'm not mac use and can't recheck, but seems like that.

Comment: I don't think it is Mac issue. I use Linux.

Comment: @vitaliis as well, but chrome works fine, with firefox there's same issue

Answer (score 1):

Use `CSS` selector to find it. Also, add wait:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#form_topsearch>.txtsrchbox.FL')))
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#form_topsearch>.txtsrchbox.FL")
inputElement.send_keys("some input")
```

add `inputElement.click()` before `inputElement.send_keys()` if above code won't work.
The problem is that Selenium does not consider your `search_str` id as unique.

Also, I think you won't need to use `inputElement.submit()` in your case. Search field does not look like a form.
From Selenium source code:

```
def submit(self):
    """Submits a form."""
    if self._w3c:
        form = self.find_element(By.XPATH, "./ancestor-or-self::form")
        self._parent.execute_script(
            "var e = arguments[0].ownerDocument.createEvent('Event');"
            "e.initEvent('submit', true, true);"
            "if (arguments[0].dispatchEvent(e)) { arguments[0].submit() }", form)
    else:
        self._execute(Command.SUBMIT_ELEMENT)
```

Comment: No its not submitting even after inputElement.submit()

Comment: Import selenium wait. Check updated answer

Comment: @vitaliis i would suggest replace self -> webelement, unclear that it's wrapper around webelement class

Comment: I cannot replace it) This method is from source code ).

Comment: @vitaliis i've thought it's your own wrapper) have you tried it in --headless mode?seems like doesn't want to search